# Xposed - How to hook the private static method

Tags: java, android, hook, xposed-framework

Xposed question:

I want to modify some static field in android.os.Build, such as android.os.Build.BOARD, android.os.Build.DEVICE, android.os.Build.DISPLAY.

There are 3 private static methods (
private static String getString(String property),
private static String[] getStringList(String property, String separator) ,
private static long getLong(String property)
) in Build.java.

Then I tried to hook the static method 'getString(String s)' in android.os.Build .

```
public void handleLoadPackage(final XC_LoadPackage.LoadPackageParam loadPackageParam) throws Throwable {

    XposedBridge.log(loadPackageParam.packageName + " -> load ");

    Class build = XposedHelpers.findClass(Build.class.getName(), loadPackageParam.classLoader);

    XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(build, "getString", String.class, new XC_MethodHook() {
        @Override
        protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
            XposedBridge.log("before ->" + param.args[0]);
            super.beforeHookedMethod(param);
        }

        @Override
        protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
            XposedBridge.log("after ->" + param.args[0]);
            super.afterHookedMethod(param);
        }
    });}
```

I try to print the first input argument in the before/after method, when I call android.os.Build.Model. But I'm wrong, it has not been triggered.

How can I hook this private static method 
in android.os.Build.java

```
private static String getString(String property) {
    return SystemProperties.get(property, UNKNOWN);}
```

Comment: did you try the [method](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/blob/master/src/de/robv/android/xposed/XposedHelpers.java) below
`code`public static Method findMethodExact(Class<?> clazz, String methodName, Object... parameterTypes) {
return findMethodExact(clazz, methodName, getParameterClasses(clazz.getClassLoader(), parameterTypes));
}`code`

Comment: @ Maddy_at_Work, 3Q, I try the code below, but it's still not right. I'm new.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void initZygote(StartupParam startupParam) throws Throwable {  

    Class clazz = XposedHelpers.findClass(android.os.Build.class.getName(), null);

    Method m = XposedHelpers.findMethodExact(clazz, "getString", String.class);

    m.setAccessible(true);

    XposedBridge.hookMethod(m, new XC_MethodHook() {
        @Override
        protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
            log("call -> " + (String) param.args[0]);
            super.beforeHookedMethod(param);
        }
    });

    String id = (String) m.invoke(null, "ro.build.id");
    log("step 1 try invoke->" + id);
    log("step 2 Call Build.ID ->" + Build.ID);
}
```

step 1 can raise beforeHookedMethod, but step 2 can not.

Comment: Were you able to address this?

Answer (score -1):

I also did something like you want recently. Check this:
https://github.com/pylerSM/XInstaller/blob/master/src/com/pyler/xinstaller/XInstaller.java#L1146