# How to hook static integer return value

Tags: java, android, xposed, xposed-framework

I have to build an app to hooking using Xposed some value from a static object but no success. This is the method I want to hook to the return value. in same to be return 10 or another value.

```
public static int somemethod () {
   return 0
}
```

What code can I use to hook this return value?

**Update Question:**

I want to change value of return to another value using xposed framework.  In my example give value 0. And i want to change that value to 20 or 10 using xposed method. Anyway i want to know xposed methode to do that.

Comment: Actually, I think this is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947591/xposed-how-to-hook-the-private-static-method.  The same techniques should be applicable to all static methods.

Comment: I want to change value of return to another value using xposed framework.  In my example give value 0. And i want to change that value to 20 or 10 using xposed method. Anyway i want to know xposed methode to do that.

Comment: can you share your hook code and the error?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod("someClass",
            loadPkgParam.classLoader, "somemethod", new XC_MethodHook() {

                @Override
                protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param)
                        throws Throwable {
                    param.setResult(neededResult);
                }

            });
```